# Socket "An invalid argument was supplied"

Tags: c#, sockets

I am using a socket for sending UDP packets in my application to a fixed IP address and port. The socket is instantiated with `Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp)` and I hold on to this instance for the entire application lifetime. Every UDP packet is transmitted using `Socket.Send(byte[] buffer)`.

The application has been running for weeks and suddenly sending throws `SocketException` with the message that *An invalid argument was supplied*. Restarting the application effectively resolves the issue, but I am interested in knowing if anyone knows what causes this and if there is any recovery strategy that I can follow.

Comment: You have to look more closely at the native error codes `SocketException` supplies. Look them up in the corresponding Windows SDK header files. They are way more informative than the message.

Comment: Ok, I replicated one scenario with the exception. If I transmit UDP packets, and I cut the network connection for the computer, a SocketException (10055) will occur followed by SocketException (10022) for every Send after this.

Comment: If you get disconnected, you should probably re-recreate the socket object.

Comment: Indeed, that seems to work for the network outage problem. If the socket is not connected, I close it and recreate it and do a new Connect. If I plug in the network, it will start submitting again.

Comment: @PeterRitchie: Post an answer with your comment and I'll mark this as the final answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you get disconnected, it's best to re-create the socket object.